# OCaml: Sys.max_array_length and minor heap size

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, arrays have a size limit of Sys.max_array_length. Since I am on a 64-bit system it turns out to be around 2^54 - 1. However, when I try

```
Array.make (Sys.max_array_length / 100) 0;;
```

It doesn't work. Specifically I get a Out_of_memory exception. I then ran this through ocamlrun and saw the following message.

```
Initial minor heap size: 2048k bytes
Initial major heap size: 992k bytes
Initial space overhead: 80%
Initial max overhead: 500%
Initial heap increment: 992k bytes
Initial allocation policy: 0
Initial stack limit: 8192k bytes
No room for growing heap
Fatal error: exception Out_of_memory
```

I then tried to increase the heap size by doing

```
export CAMLRUNPARAM='s=18014398k'
```

This gave me a new message:

```
Initial minor heap size: 2097152k bytes
Initial major heap size: 992k bytes
Initial space overhead: 80%
Initial max overhead: 500%
Initial heap increment: 992k bytes
Initial allocation policy: 0
Initial stack limit: 8192k bytes
No room for growing heap
Fatal error: exception Out_of_memory
```

In fact, I cannot increase the minor heap size anymore as it will say that it cannot initialize the page table. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but it seems  like it's not actually possible to create arrays of length Sys.max_array_length - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entry in an array on a 64-bit system will occupy 8 bytes (say). If you want an array of 2^54 of those, this will require 128 petabytes of address space. Most likely your system doesn't allow processes that large.

In other words, it's not at all surprising that you can't create an array that large.

It's a good point that on a 64-bit system the `Sys.max_array_length` is only giving an upper bound based on the particulars of the OCaml data representation. It's not saying that your specific system will support an array that large.

**Update**

If you're actually trying to figure out size limits imposed on data on a particular system, you need to investigate the system you're working on. On a 64-bit system, you're not realistically going to hit the limits imposed by OCaml until systems get much, much more powerful than they are now. The `Sys.max_array_length` value just isn't interesting until then. The only interesting limits are the ones imposed by the system you're using.

**Update 2**

I don't know if this helps, but here is the code for `Sys.max_array_length`:

```
let max_array_length = (1 lsl (word_size - 10)) - 1
```

Note that it's returning a *constant* value based on the word size of the machine. It always returns the same value on all 64-bit machines, and is not at all useful to determine how much space is going to be available to a particular process in a particular circumstance.

Comment: Thanks, so how does this work for strings which have a variable length? Does it internally store a "pointer" to the string instead then? Or does it use the size of the initial element passed in to Array.make to determine how much space will be needed. Another issue is that I cannot even make an array of size 1 billion.

Comment: The `Sys.max_string_length` value is overpromising in exactly the same way. I don't think the OCaml string representation has much to do with this question, but it's laid out in [Chapter 19](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec425) of the OCaml manual.

Comment: Oh I meant what if I wanted an array of strings, how would it know how big the array of strings could be?

Comment: Because the value is only an upper limit, the value is the same for all array types on a 64-bit system. On a 32-bit system, the limit on float arrays is smaller. (I just read this in the manual.) But the value isn't telling you how big a particular array can be in a particular circumstance on a particular system. It's just an upper bound imposed by the OCaml data representation.

Comment: Ah I understand that part now, I might be missing the point because I don't seem to be able to even make an array of size 1 billion. I thought that would only take 8 billion bytes, which should be possible. The Out_of_Memory message suggest otherwise.

Comment: I think I understand now, I probably don't have 8 GB available for the array in memory.